# Display which button to press depending on user input method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game is using the old input manager system. When the player collides with a specific object it enables the player to throw projectiles. What I'd like to do is when they collide with it, briefly display a ui prompt showing which button to press.

So, if the user is on a gamepad, I want to find out which kind it is and the ui prompt should tell the user which button to press, so like square if on a ps4 controller. If m&kb tell them to click lmb.

Not exactly sure where to start.

Comment: Use the new input system and then https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_PlayerInput_currentControlScheme

Comment: Can I use it just for this? I don't really want to switch all my code to use the new input system. Maybe this is a dumb question. I'm new to Unity but in my post I stated that I'm using the old input manager. I don't want to switch everything to support the new input system just to see what device the player is using. Was this not possible before the new input system??

Comment: Here's what people did in the old days, not very great https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-whether-controller-or-keyboard-is-being-used-via-script.359608/#post-3349666